# Unable to continue Wagtail installation, "./migrate.py migrate" traceback

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, linode, wagtail

I'm installing Wagtail on Linode Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I followed the following guides so far:

- https://www.linode.com/docs/getting-started
- http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/index.html

For the second link, I followed the installation guides for Python, pip, virtualenv and the required Pillow libs.

I got up to the following in the installation process:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ ./manage.py migrate
```

The migrate command produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I haven't been able to find a solution for this. I am doing all of this in venv. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you use `$ wagtail start mysite` command? What is the output of `cat requirements.txt`?

Comment: Django>=1.10,<1.11
    wagtail>=1.9,<1.10
@pawel.ad

Comment: So I tried `pip install django` and it said requirements satisfied. I then tried `pip install Django` and it installed Django-1.10.6. Is that weird?

Comment: Great, so I retried the migrate command and got a different traceback. http://pastebin.com/ZhHNnPBq

Comment: I ran into another wall so I'm completely redeploying and starting from scratch. Thanks everyone that clicked into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by re-doing everything. Created new virtualenv, activated, and continued from there. Everything seems to be working correctly so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That error suggests that Django hasn't been installed.

What is the output of `pip install -r requirements.txt`?